# Extract the properties from .rfa file in a web browser or cloud

Tags: extract, autodesk-forge, autodesk, revit-api, autodesk-model-derivative

I need to extract the object properties from Revit families to save them in a cloud-based platform, preferably without using the Autodesk Revit desktop software.
I've tried Autodesk Forge platform but it doesn't seem to support .rfa formats directly.
Is there any suitable Autodesk Revit API Or additional features on Autodesk forge platform that extract Revit Family parameters with .rfa format on a web browser or a cloud-based platform without converting the .rfa format to the others like .rvt or .obj?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, absolutely. You are semi-correct in the statement that the [Autodesk Platform Services APS](https://aps.autodesk.com/) (formerly Forge) do not support `RFA` in the respect the the [APS Design Automation API](https://aps.autodesk.com/design-automation-apis) can be used to process `RVT` projects, but not `RFA` ones. However, the statement is also incorrect, because APS DA can be used to open and process an `RFA` file included in its payload. Thus, APS DA can absolutely be used to extract the properties you are after, and several examples of doing so exist. For instance, check out the AU class on [Using Design Automation for Revit for Displaying RFAs in the Forge Viewer](https://www.autodesk.com/autodesk-university/class/Using-Design-Automation-Revit-Displaying-RFAs-Forge-Viewer-2020)
.

Comment: Here is also an example we made during the accelerator event: https://github.com/xiaodongliang/aps-tutorial-design.automation-rfa-to-rvt